# How to use internal Log4NetLogProvider using identity server

Tags: identityserver3

I try to setup logger provider using next piece of code

```
LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new Log4NetLogProvider());
```

But i have compilation errors, because Log4NetLogProvider has been defined as internal in LibLog.cs (IdentityServer code).
How to configure IdentityServer for using Log4NetLogProvider (internal implementation) ?

Comment: Have you looked at the logging docs? https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/logging.html

Comment: @BrockAllen The issue is that it's really easy when searching to wind up on https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/configuration/logging.html and get frustrated when the classes you're supposed to instantiate are internal.

Comment: If it's a bug or you feel like it's one, then open an issue on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

I have log4net in my project from before I added identity server, it just works for me, I did not have to change anything that I had done.
so in my case I had got the nuget package created the table and updated my web.config to use log4net before I added identity server.
if you want a sample of my setup I can add it later.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled with this yesterday.  The documentation I believe is not totally correct.  The important thing to know is that identityserver code will detect a certain set of 3rd party logging libraries.  Log4Net is one they recognize.  So if you configure your app to use log4Net, then identityserver will detect this and start logging to it as well without any additional configuration needed.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It is very helpful for me!